# Accessing files at media directory

Tags: url, ce-1.9.0.1, media

I uploaded additional files for products. They get stored in media folder in Magento root directory. How can I access files stored at media folder in Magento root folder? Should I use a method for accessing files outside Root directory or simply involve a direct access code in php?

Answer (score 1):

It depends from where you want to call that access from; there's 2 possibilities:

1. from within the Magento Administration - say, a CMS page or a Block. There, you can refer to the 'media' directory via
2. from a template-file (phtml)

   1. refer to the skin directory:

      ```
      <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/filename.jpg')?>"
      ```
   2. refer to the media directory:

      ```
      <?php echo  Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA); ?>
      ```

There's also plenty of sources:

See [Magento-Forum](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/289595/) or [stanleytips.com](http://stanleytips.com/magento-how-to-get-skin-url-get-media-url-get-base-url-get-store-url/) for starters

Comment: So I should use Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA); where URL_TYPE_MEDIA is the path to the media directory?

Comment: If you work with a template file (*.phtml) - yes, that's what I would try first.